# Interfaces to allow unit's ability to attack ground, air, or both in Java using Design Patterns

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, interface, abstract-class

Im making a text game that has an abstract Fighter class. within Fighter I have a variable called   protected boolean isGround. then I have 2 abstract classes that extend Fighter called AirFighter and GroundFighter that basically set that isGround to be True or False, depending on if they are ground units or not.

I then want to set up the game so that in my battle phase the game checks if player 1's speed is faster then player 2, and depending on who is faster to then do like p1.attack(p2), and print out the stats of that battle, like the remaining health of each player or something like that.

I want a way for some airFighters to attack air, or attack air and ground, and I want some groundFighters to attack ground only, or ground and air. How would I go about doing this while staying loosely coupled? It is for a design pattern's class and its frustrating me. Is there a design pattern to help me with this?

Think of the game starcraft, that's basically what my game is mimicing, certain units like a marine can attack ground and air, some air units can only attack air, some can do both. I want to be able to do this without having some nasty if else checking statement.

Comment: What a great post title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to have a method in the base `Fighter` that can be used to check if that `Fighter` can attack another:

```
public abstract class Fighter {
    public abstract boolean isGround ();
    public abstract boolean canAttack (Fighter target);
}
```

Subclasses can then override `canAttack` and make an appropriate decision. For example:

```
public class SurfaceToAirLauncher extends Fighter {
    @Override public boolean isGround () {
        // missile launcher is on the ground
        return true; 
    }
    @Override public boolean canAttack (Fighter target) {
        // we can only attack air targets
        return (target != null && !target.isGround());
    }
}

public class Dragon extends Fighter {
    @Override public boolean isGround () {
        // dragons are in the air
        return false; 
    }
    @Override public boolean canAttack (Fighter target) {
        // dragons can attack every target.
        return (target != null);
    }
}

public class Knight extends Fighter {
    @Override public boolean isGround () {
        // knights are on the ground
        return true; 
    }
    @Override public boolean canAttack (Fighter target) {
        // knights can only attack dragons
        return (target != null && target instanceof Dragon);
    }
}
```

You could remove the check for `null` if you know `target` will never be `null`. I included it for completeness.

Comment: Thank you! this helped, and although I dont think it uses any patterns it was better than what I had previously. maybe strategy pattern?

Comment: I like to call it the "common sense pattern". Not everything has to be labeled as some kind of pattern. Programmers call things "patterns" because it is an easy way for us to communicate our experiences of what techniques work well to other programmers. Use the best tool for the job. Focus on keeping your code precise, clear, reusable, and maintainable. Do not focus on using a "pattern" just for the sake of using one. Your specific case is very simple, a base class with common methods is more than sufficient -- don't over-complicate just so you can label your code as some kind of "pattern".

Comment: (Not that what you're asking isn't understandable; during the learning process it's totally reasonable to gravitate towards familiar things, such as the concept of "patterns" -- I think the applicable cliche saying here is "When you only have a hammer, every problem looks like a nail.")

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest the Decorator pattern.  You have a SimpleFighter as your base class (which has an canAttack(Fighter enemy) method that just returns false), and a FighterDecorator, both that implement the Fighter interface.  See how to set up the constructor and delegating methods here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Then you have two classes that extend the FighterDecorator:

The GroundKillerDecorator that has a canAttack() method that says:

```
if(enemy.isGround) return true; else return super.canAttack();
```

The AirKillerDecorator that has a canAttack() method that says:

```
if(!enemy.isGround) return true; else return super.canAttack();
```

...

And that should let you compose your fighters like

```
new GroundKillerDecorator( new AirKillerDecorator( new SimpleFighter() ))
```

Optimally, you could replace SimpleFighter with two other classes, AirFighter and GroundFighter, that implement different base behavior (rather than not being able to attack anything by default), but still implement the same Fighter interface.

Comment: thanks for responding, i had finished / fixed my problem using the above solution before I read yours, but yours would work too.

Comment: Decorators let you essentially define subclasses dynamically at runtime instead of being locked into compile time definitions. The OP doesn't have any requirements like that, this only serves to obfuscate code with a bunch of delegate methods without any actual design benefit. The OP doesn't have the problem that decorators are intended to solve. Recall the OP's problem is that he wants to avoid a big, twisted `if` statement -- it's nothing more than a classic example of the usefulness of subclassing things. Keep it simple!

Comment: Completely true.  Simple first.  Had a "design pattern" mindset late last night, but inheritance is a design pattern too.